# How do you find the index of a character in a string?

Tags: python, function, indexing, character

I'm trying to create a program that finds the index of a character in a string,(without using any functions other than range,if statements, while loops,or for loops) but I can't figure out how to do it. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def findIndex(char, test):
    while char!=testList:
        for i in range(len(test)):
            if i!=char:
                i+=1
    if char==test:
        print i


print findIndex("e", "alphabet")
```

Comment: `"alphabet".index("e")` is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def find_index(needle, haystack):
    for i in range(len(haystack)):
        if needle == haystack[i]:
            return i
    else:
        return -1    # didn't find it
```

Answer (score 0):

what is missing in your code:

1. **NameError:** `testList` variable is not define, so `NameError` exception will come.
2. **range():** As range function return list of integers. In code you are checking integer value with character i.e. `if i!=char:` which must be like `if test[i]==char` and print or return in this if loop.
3. **No** need to **while** loop.
4. **Last if loop:** **No** need to last if loop. You are checking character with whole string which will never True. Only True when string with only one search character.

demo:

```
>>> range(3)
[0, 1, 2]
```

---

By **enumerate**:

1. Get character value from user by `raw_input()`. If user enters multiple characters then take first character for processing.

   2. Check character is present in target string. If not present then return `-1` i.e. `-1` means character is not found in string.
   3. Use `enumerate()` to iterate string.
   4. Check each items from the string is equal to search character or not.
   5. If yes then return index value.

code:

```
def findIndex(char, target_inoout):
    if char in target_inoout:
        for i, value in enumerate(target_inoout):
            if char==value:
                return i
    else:
        return -1



char = raw_input("Enter singal Character:").strip()[0]

rs = findIndex(char, "alphabet")
if rs==-1:
    print "Character %s is not found."%(char)
else:
    print "Character %s is found at: %d"%(char, rs)
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 31.py 
Enter singal Character:e
Character e is found at: 6
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 31.py 
Enter singal Character:z
Character z is not found.
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```

---

For Multiple character in string:

code:

```
def findIndex(char, target_inoout):

    if char in target_inoout:
        result = []
        for i, value in enumerate(target_inoout):
            if char==value:
                result.append(i)
        return result
    else:
        return None



char = raw_input("Enter singal Character:").strip()[0]

rs = findIndex(char, "alphabet with some more values.")
if rs:
    print "Character %s is found at: %s"%(char, rs)
else:
    print "Character %s is not found."%(char)
```

Output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 31.py 
Enter singal Character:m
Character m is found at: [16, 19]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 31.py 
Enter singal Character:z
Character z is not found.
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```